# Rename public to private with gofmt

Tags: go

I am working on cleaning up someone else's code, and so I want to remove unused functions. I tried this:

```
staticcheck
```

but it only finds unused private functions. So I thought maybe I can edit everything to be private. I tried this:

```
gofmt -w -r 'SomeFunction -> someFunction' *.go
```

but that only works for one function. Is it possible to rename all public functions to private functions?

Comment: This makes no sense. Go can tell which "private" methods are unused by looking at a module because those methods, by definition, cannot be used outside the module. If you make *all* methods private, than the whole module is *by definition* useless and *every* method will be unused. You can't tell whether the public methods you're worried about are used with static code analysis because the users of those functions live outside of your codebase, that's what public methods are *for*.

Comment: @user229044 I will only be exporting one function, so I will know to ignore removal suggestion for that one. Once everything is cleaned up, I can export it again

Comment: Why not merely have a list of all exported symbols from a package and then `grep` the code which is supposed to use them? If a symbol is not used, it may be a candidate for unexporting. Actually, the problem as stated sounds weird: is the code _that_ bad that is sort of exports everything? I mean, in any sensible codebase what to export and what to not export is not a decision to make _mechanically._

Comment: One minor point: have you considered making the offending package [internal](https://go.dev/doc/go1.4#internalpackages)? This feature approaches the problem of "over-exporting" from another angle.

Comment: @kostix I am starting with another package. I only need one of the exported functions, and any internal functions that it relies on.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of exported symbols, you can use `go doc that/package`. To also have all the exported methods for each type in one single call, use `go doc -all that/package` .

You can then either store the result in a file and edit it, or add a bit of script fu to extract the names you want.

From that, you can generate a script which replaces the symbols you want to.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that solves the problem. I don't need a list of exported symbols. I need a list of unused symbols, or a means to unexport everything

Comment: @three, you can then iterate over that list running your `gofmt` encantation on each of them. I mean, it can be scripted.

Comment: @three : as kostix said, I suggested that as a quick hack to apply your "unexport and check what gets reported as unused" trick. Otherwise: is that package so big ? another way is to simply delete some code and see if the compiler complains.